# how to use the :target selector to affect different elements?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have two div's covering two forms. each time someone clicks on one cover the form reveals. the problem is i want to change the display of one of the submit buttons to "display:none" each time someone click's on one of the covers. any way i can use the :target selector to commit actions on other elements in the same HTML page?

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <!--The cover of the women form-->
    <div id="wcover"><h1><a href="#wcover">MALE</a> </h1></div>

    <form id="women">
             ...    
    </form>

    <input type="submit" form="women" value="Submit" class="submitButton" id="womenSubmit">

    <!--The cover of the men form-->
    <div id="mcover"><h1><a href="#mcover">FEMALE</a></div>

    <form id="men">
             ...
    </form>

    <input type="submit" form="men" value="Submit" class="submitButton" id="menSubmit">
</div>
```

css:

```
#mcover{
    left: 183px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 131px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 337px;
    height: 355px;
    background: #f4f4f2;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: height 2s;
}   


#wcover{
    right: 183px;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 131px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 337px;
    height: 355px;
    background: #f4f4f2;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: height 2s;
}   

#mcover:target {
    height: 0px;

}


#wcover:target {
    height: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

the below is the Adjacent Sibling Selector

```
'#mcover:target + input.submitButton{
display:none;
}'
```

to select all elements that are siblings

```
'#mcover:target ~ input.submitButton{
display:none;
}'
```

Comment: Great, did you manage to fix the "How can I make css transition last after unhovering?" Check my solution for that and see if it works. cheers.